# Send Array of Api Request for Server in Soap iOS

Tags: ios, swift, soap

i am using third party Exigo Api request for my app. the service says to send 2 more requests array in the body of main Soap service. Though i tried sending the 2 request in string form in the Body of the main request but i received Empty String . Help me out how should i do this . i got no solution in the manual or on any other site after googling this issue for a week i am posting this question

[Exigo Api (Process Transaction Service)](http://api.exigo.com/3.0/ExigoApi.asmx?op=ProcessTransaction)

```
POST /3.0/ExigoApi.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: api.exigo.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://api.exigo.com/ProcessTransaction"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
      xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <ApiAuthentication xmlns="http://api.exigo.com/">
      <LoginName>string</LoginName>
      <Password>string</Password>
      <Company>string</Company>
    </ApiAuthentication>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <TransactionalRequest xmlns="http://api.exigo.com/">
      <TransactionRequests>
        <ApiRequest />
      </TransactionRequests>
    </TransactionalRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is the Soap request i have to process and Send Api Request Array in the body of the main request using iOS. 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Please check below link, like

let body = envelope.addChild(name: "soap:Body")

let header = body.addChild(name: "soap:Header" , attributes: ["xmlns:m" : "http://www.w3schools.com/transaction/"])

https://github.com/tadija/AEXML

Comment: instead of soap header use TransactionalRequest

Answer (score 0):

We have tackle same type of issue for our mobile app. We have have implemented adapter that accepts JSON request from Mobile and then translate that into API request which is inculded in MVC Application as wsdl. Can't find any other way to do that.